# What is the inverse of bitwise AND in C#?

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

I need to do an inverse calculation, which consists bitwise AND operation,how do I do it?

I tried exclusive OR, but it didn't help.

```
        int i = 254 & 2;
        Console.Write("254 & 2 ={0}", i + "\n");
        Console.Write("{0} ^ 2 ={1}",i, (i ^ 2) + "\n");
```

Doesn't work. How do I do that calculation?

Comment: When you say "Doesn't work" what do you mean?  It compiles and produces the expected result for me.  What result does it display for you, and more importantly what result do you want it to display for you?

Comment: The only reversible bitwise operation you have is XOR, so `(a^b)^b==a`. If you want to reverse your operation and you aren't dead set on using AND, try this instead.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Given `i`, you cannot get back `254`. By `&`ing it you have destroyed what data was not stored in the second bit.

```
 1111 1110
&0000 0010
----------
 0000 0010
```

How would you recover the 6 lost bits? For `x & 2 == 2`, you could put almost any `x` and it would be true.

```
 0010 1010 // = 42
&0000 0010
----------
 0000 0010
```

Is `x` 254 or 42? You cannot tell.

Answer (score 22):

Technically the opposite of AND is NAND:

> ~( 254 & 2 )

Note that the ~ is the complement operator, and does a bitwise NOT (toggle each bit to its opposite).

What exactly do you want, though?  What are you trying to accomplish?

If you're trying to undo the calculation, you can't - there is no inverse function such that inverseand(and(x, y)) will return x or y, even if inverse is given one of them.

Comment: +1 partially because I *think* you're on the right track, but mostly because of the "what do you want" question, which is really the issue here...it's not completely obvious what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, you've lost the data that was there when you did the &.

4-bit example:

```
1110 & 0010 = 0010
```

You have no way of knowing which bits were 1 and which weren't if you only know the result 0010 and the second operand of the & (also 0010).

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a good article on bitwise operations, how they work and their syntax in C and Java which is very similar to C#

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

MSDN of course also has documentation for each of the bitwise and logical operators each of which have an example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by opposite calculation?

If you see the number 254 as an bit register consisting of 8 bits then all bits but the last is set to 1.

Calculating 254 & 2 is the same as checking whether bit number 2 in the register is set.

What is the opposite of this? Checking if all other bits are set?

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of the `&` operation is to check whether bit 1 is set, then a potential "opposite" operation is 'set bit 1'.

i.e.:

```
val = val | 2;
```

This overwrites the value currently in bit 2, and doesn't touch any other bit.

If the 8 bits in the byte are considered to be completely independent bits then it's possible to change any of them with touching any of the others.

In this case, it doesn't matter that some of the original information was lost.  We don't actually care what value the other bits had, and most often when using bit masks the original value of the bit in question was zero anyway.